# When I type to fast on input it renders the wrong div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, vuejs2, debouncing

I'm have to show two different dropdown in my input.
I'm doing it by having an shouldShowWarningBox method that it's called every time the input is updated by the user an updates the value of showWarningBox.
The point is, when I type to fast I receive a false showing the warning message, but it's not true. If I type slowly the first div is rendered.

I've tried with and without the debounce function, but the behavior is the same, just with a little delay.

Any ideas?

.html

```
<div v-if="!showWarningBox">
 //dropbox
</div>

<div v-if="showWarningBox">
 //warning message
</div>
```

.js

```
data () {
 return {
  showWarningBox: false,
 }
},
methods: {
 onInput (value) {
  this.debounce(this.shouldShowWarningBox(), 1000)
 },
 shouldShowWarningBox () {
  //conditional that changes showWarningBox
 },
 debounce (func, delay) {
  let id
 
  return (...args) => {
   if (id) clearTimeout(id)

   id = setTimeout(() => {
    func(...args)
   }, delay)
  }
 },
}
```

Comment: you are not debouncing your function, but calling it right away. it should be: `this.debounce(this.shouldShowWarningBox, 1000)`

Comment: True, I fixed it. I put a console inside the debounce return but it does not console anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`debounce` returns a "debounced" function. You should save that function in a component property and call that debounced function on input:

```
data(){
  let debouncedFn = this.debounce(this.shouldShowWarningBox, 1000)
  return {
    debouncedInput: debouncedFn
  }
},
methods: {
 onInput (value) {
  this.debouncedInput()
 },
 //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In the end was a different matter to be resolved, in the conditional I was using looking at an array that was having an "delay" - don't know if that is the best word, but it took one interaction to update, I solved it using an watcher and did not use a debugger.